# await does not wait in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have declared 2 methods as `findSuitableRoom` and `getRooms`. The `getRooms` function is calling inside the `findSuitableRoom` method. I want to wait until the `getRooms` function executed. Since I used `async/await`. Yet it does not wait.

Implementations :-

```
async function findSuitableRoom(_lecturer, _sessionDay, _sessionTime, _sessionDuration, _sessionType){

       //other implementations

       rooms = await getRooms(_sessionType, lecturer.fullName);
       console.log("FindSuitableRoom function "+rooms.length)
       response = await assignRoom(rooms, _sessionDuration, lecturer.level, lecturer.fullName);

}
```

```
async function getRooms(type){

    let roomsByType = "";

    await Rooms.find({type : type},
       async (err, rooms) => {
            if (rooms){
                roomsByType = rooms;

                console.log("Get Room Function "+roomsByType.length)
            } else {
                console.log('No Rooms')
            }
        })

    return roomsByType;
}
```

I used **console.log()** to get the length of responses. It printed in the console as below

```
Get Room Function 6
FindSuitableRoom function 6
FindSuitableRoom function 0
Get Room Function 5
Get Room Function 6
FindSuitableRoom function 6
Get Room Function 6
FindSuitableRoom function 6
```

What changes do I need to add in order to make this functionality **synchronous**?

Comment: Try using an if statement in findSuitableRoom. Also, you can always add .then() to the end of getRooms and handle from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you use `await` then you should directly collect the result of the function instead of using a callback.

```js
async function getRooms(type) {

    let roomsByType = [];

    let roomsByType = await Rooms.find({ type: type });

    if (roomsByType.length) {
        console.log("Get Room Function " + roomsByType.length)
    } else {
        console.log('No Rooms')
    }
    return roomsByType;
}
```